# Update All Instances of matching letter in ArrayList

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I am trying to update a String ArrayList that contains letters if a certain letter exists in another ArrayList. But, the code only updates the first instance that it encounters instead of all instances. The ArrayList word contains the letters h,e,l,l,o, ,w,o,r,l,d and the ArrayList underscores contains underscores corresponding for each letter in word. For every letter in word I want to get it's index and update underscores with that letter at that same index. For example, for the l, I want to update underscores to show underscores except for the indexes where the letter l is found in word.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> word = new ArrayList<String>();
    word.add("h");
    word.add("e");
    word.add("l");
    word.add("l");
    word.add("o");
    word.add(" ");
    word.add("w");
    word.add("o");
    word.add("r");
    word.add("l");
    word.add("d");

    for (String letter:word) {
      System.out.print(letter);
    }

    System.out.println();

    ArrayList<String> underscores = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String letter:word) {
      if (letter.equals(" ")) {
        underscores.add(" ");
      } else {
        underscores.add("-");
      }
    }

    for (String letter: underscores) {
      System.out.print(letter);
    }
    String l = "l";
    for (String s:word) {
      if (s.equals(l)) {
        int index = word.indexOf(s);
        underscores.set(index, l);
      }
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (String s:underscores) {
      System.out.print(s);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you also include clear input and the expected output, including data for all edge cases?

Comment: Why are you using an `ArrayList<String>` to represent a collection of characters? Either use an `ArrayList<Character>`, or use a single `String`, and iterate over its character array.

Comment: Your "problem" is that you look up the index  in word and updating in underscore. Word allways is 'hello world', word.indexOf(s) gives you every time the first index of "l".

Comment: @Eran When I first read this question, what popped out in my mind was why not just use regex replacement?  But, maybe the assignment requires this type of approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `word.indexOf(s)` returns always the index of first occurence of given element. From [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-) docs :

> Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element. More formally, returns the lowest index i such that (o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i))), or -1 if there is no such index.

Instead of using `for-each` loop you can use simple old `for` loop to update Strings at given positions in `underscores` list :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < underscores.size(); i++) {
    if (word.get(i).equals(l)) {
        underscores.set(i, l);
    }
}
```

and the output will be :

```
hello world
----- -----
--ll- ---l-
```

Comment: Thank you michalk! That worked perfectly with what I was trying to do unsuccessfully. Awesome.